# hide cursor movement in textbox

Tags: html

I want to hide cursor movement in text box.

Comment: Please add some details to this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
textarea {
   cursor: none;
}
```

That is what I gathered from your question.

I don't know if it is always such a good idea, it could be quite confusing for your users if their cursor disappears.

Comment: not supported in all browsers